# NodeJs/React- How to store query results from firestore in variable

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-firestore

```
function collectres () {
  var store ='';
  var docRef = db.collection("cities").doc("SF");
  docRef.get()
    .then(function (doc) {
      if (doc.exists) {
        console.log("Document data:", doc.data());
        store = doc.data();// when referenced outside, it doesnt hold anything.
      } else {
        // doc.data() will be undefined in this case
        console.log("No such document!");
      }
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
      console.log("Error getting document:", error);
    });
  return store; // returns nothing and seems to not notice the assignment.
}
```

I have this problem, where i want to store firebase query results into a variable. However, when i try and assign the variable some data from the query, it seems to not be able to store it. 
Any help or advice in the right direction would help.

Edit 1:
After implementing the callback function, i was wondering how to set the state for a component or permanently store the results so that many components can access it.

```
user.CollectRes(function(store){
      console.log(store.name);
      name =store.name;
      console.log(name);
     // this.setState({name:store.name});
    });
    console.log(name); // want to be able to reference this outside the callback function. So i can display it on the page.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because JavaScript is asynchrone.

Because of that, your variable `doc` doesn't exists yet outside your `.then` function.

To return this value, you can use [Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Promise) way, or easier, you can have a callback function to return your document like this :

```
function collectres (callback) {
    var docRef = db.collection("cities").doc("SF");
    docRef.get().then(function (doc) {
        if (doc && doc.exists) {
            callback(doc.data()); // Return your data inside the callback function
        } else {
            callback(null); // Return null if data doesn't exists
        }
    }).catch(function (error) {
        callback(null); // Return null in error case
    });
}

collectres(function (store) { // Call collectres to get your data
    console.log(store);
    // continue here
});
```

I recommand you to read [this article](https://medium.com/codebuddies/getting-to-know-asynchronous-javascript-callbacks-promises-and-async-await-17e0673281ee) to learn more about asynchronous.

Hope it helps.

Comment: This worked Thank you. If it wouldnt be troublesome, i am also using react and i was wondering how to load the data into the state.